# access to jenkins shared pipeline library through a corporate proxy

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using jenkins 2 and I'm trying to use the shared library functionality.
I'm trying to fetch a jenkins pipeline shared library (stored in gitlab.com) through a corporate proxy. I configured a modern GIT scm .
Despite of I can  fetch directly this repository in a jenkins job, I can't download the library during an other project's build.

How can I fix that ? Do you think it's a bug ?

Comment: I think it is a bug. You can create ticket in jenkins jira https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As temporary solution you can setup local nexus repository which proxying maven central.

Comment: The only workaournd founded is to create a script refered in jenkins as git path which contains these lines :


`#!/bin/sh`
`export http_proxy=http://.....`
`export https_proxy=http://....`
`/usr/bin/git $@`

Comment: I guess if you have the corporate proxy you must have the corporate repository =) I think my solution is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't know that both artifactory/nexus provide git repository proxy. You' re right

Comment: Small clarification: artifactory/nexus is artifact repository, git is source code repository. After source code is built produced artifact is deploying to artifact repository.

Comment: You can use Artifactory as git (eg github) proxy

Comment: Thank you for info.